# How to calculate the min in matlab

Tags: matlab, weka

So I am doing tutorials as I am a beginner on matlab. I have recorded accelerator data using a shimmer device this is recording 9 minutes of activities then loading the txt file on to matlab, getting the features, creating an arff file and exploring the confusion matrix etc (I would edit the txt file matlab produces and change it to arff file. I have successfully got the mean however now I want to calculate the min and then the max ( I am doing this seprately but if anyone knows how to do this all on the one script that would be brilliant)

```
for i = 1:totalWindows
  epMin = min(lowrow(startPos:endPos,:)); %calculate window min

  %X, Y & Z axis values for each stat
  lowrowminfeatures(i,1:3) = epMin; 

  %Next window position
   startPos = endPos+1;
   endPos = startPos + (windowLength * floor(Fq));
end

 windowLength = 5; %Length for each window in seconds
  startPos = 1; %Starting Position for 1st win
  endPos = startPos + (windowLength * floor(Fq)); %End Position for 1st win
 totalWindows = floor(length(fly)/Fq/windowLength);

stats = zeros(windowLength,9);

for i = 1:totalWindows
  epMin = min(fly(startPos:endPos,:)); %calculate window min

   %X, Y & Z axis values for each stat
  flyminfeatures(i,1:3) = epMin; 

  %Next window position
   startPos = endPos+1;
   endPos = startPos + (windowLength * floor(Fq));
end

 windowLength = 5; %Length for each window in seconds
  startPos = 1; %Starting Position for 1st win
  endPos = startPos + (windowLength * floor(Fq)); %End Position for 1st win
 totalWindows = floor(length(pull)/Fq/windowLength);

 stats = zeros(windowLength,9);

for i = 1:totalWindows
  epMin = min(pull(startPos:endPos,:)); %calculate window min

  %X, Y & Z axis values for each stat
  pullminfeatures(i,1:3) = epMin; 

%Next window position
startPos = endPos+1;
endPos = startPos + (windowLength * floor(Fq));

end
```

save  ('wekafilemin.txt','lowrowminfeatures','flyminfeatures','pullminfeatures','-ascii')

**How do I get the wakefilemin to save it did when I calculated mean now it wont for the min** - when I run this m file the txt file does not generate

the text file should come up something like this:

[image: features on txt file]

thank you very much

Comment: Your question title is very misleading, in regards to the question, have you looked here? (http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/save.html)

Comment: As @ScottStainton mentions your question title is misleading, or you didn't ask the question clearly. I don't understand you're text much except that you want to know how to save the text file. If so why did you share your script and ask about min? I suggest you review your question and details so it is clear enough to answer otherwise community users will down vote it. It happened to me.

Comment: Hi Guys! I apologise that my question is misleading I am a new starter to matlab. I just want to know how I can get this script to generate the txt file and window the data for me. I got this wroking previously for the mean however when I run this feature the save ('wekafilemin.txt') does not generate for me

Comment: Any error while running?

Comment: @laurajs When you run the save command what do you get? Do you get an error? What is it?